# How to create a thread safe customized HTML Result in Testng

Tags: java, multithreading, testng, selenium-grid

I am learning selenium grid and testng.

I am trying to create customized html result using testng interfaces. my understanding on how to create html results is fine in a single machine execution.

But when i factor remote machines, i am not able to understand like how results are consolidated if tests are executed in parallel in remote machines?

Any factors should i consider before implementing my own interfaces?

Any help is appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, from multi-threaded tests to the HTML report because the ITestResult is always the same in the end, no matter what you do.  You can simple create a "CustomReport" class that extends IReporter.  Then, override the generateReport method and just let TestNG create and pass these 2 arguments into it:

```
@Override
public void generateReport( List<XmlSuite> xml, List<ISuite> suites, String outdir ) 
{
    for ( ISuite thisSuite: suites ) {
       thisSuite.getResults(). ...
       ...
    }
    ....
```

Then, inside that method, do what you will, to customize the report and generate HTML tables or whatever.

Also, one thing I do (to reduce confusion in the console output while multithreaded tests run) is log the thread name to messages on the TestNG report by using something like:

```
public void logIt( String message ) {
  Reporter.log( "Thread-" + Thread.currentThread().getId() + ": " + message, true );
}
```

TestNG is awesome, especially when you understand what I said above as well as the fact that you implicitly allow TestNG to pass a XMLTest or ITestContext or ITestResult to some of the @Configuration methods.  For example:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp( ITestContext context ) {
    logger.info("BeforeClass setUp...");
    suiteParams = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getAllParameters();
    ...
```